# Identity Magen David/Star of David symbol with K in the middle certification

Tags: hechsher-certification

I have seen a kosher symbol with a Magen David and a K in the middle on a few product. I tried to google specific keywords but could not find anything. So I will attach a screenshot I found.[image]

Comment: Hi jess welcome to Mi Yodeya! I was unable to locate this on standard lists of kosher symbols. It would help us identify it if you could specify what city you purchased this in, and if the product states where it is manufactured.

Comment: Another strategy is to contact the company on whose product you found this and ask them the name of the agency.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Dovid Katz, 1122 Ave L, Brooklyn, NY 11230. (718) 951-9205; (917) 246-8031.

http://www.kashrusmagazine.com/ksg/nyc/brooklyn.htm

From "The Kosher Suervision Guide"(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJD3A.jpg)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Meir and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!